# Scikit install asks for Scipy even though it is installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to install Scikit by running:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

When I run it, I get this message:

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.18.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-3080ikpy\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';f=getatt
r(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-04zx4iu6-record\i
nstall-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3080ikpy\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 149, in get_scipy_status
        import scipy
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
        from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
    ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3080ikpy\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 270, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3080ikpy\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 260, in setup_package
        .format(scipy_req_str, instructions))
    ImportError: Scientific Python (SciPy) is not installed.
    scikit-learn requires SciPy >= 0.9.
    Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
```

Which seems to ask me to install Scipy, however I already have Scipy installed, and indeed if I run

```
pip install scipy
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\python36\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from scipy)
```

Comment: What version of scipy do you have installed?

Comment: I have version 0.19 32 bit

Comment: Do you have numpy and mkl already installed on your machine? Then you will try to install scipy. Easiest way to get the Scipy ecosystem working probably is picking up all those packages there: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: @Nadni you're using NumPy MKL you need the same SciPy and ScikitLearn installed let me dig up the link and post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your install shows this: `from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl` `ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'`

So you need to do a few things.  Get the right SciPy: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Get the right NumPy: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Get the right SciKit Learn: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sci-kitlearn

Now do `pip uninstall` each of your other packages.  Then do `pip install` the wheels you downloaded at those links provided - NumPy 1st, SciPy 2nd, then Ski-kitlearn last.  That should then solve your issue. Note at those links you're downloading the files with `cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`or `cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` depending on if you have 32bit or 64bit Python installed.

Comment: Thanks but why isn't this handled in install dependencies?